# How to achieve swipe animation in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

I don't know about animation so pls guide me how to make this type of animation in react native

[Splash animation](https://www.kapwing.com/videos/64bd30a9edaa9f00d11a74c9)

| want this type of animation I hope you get this idea , pls help and thanksin advance, I try last two days but i don't know how to achieve this type of animation in react native

Answer (score 0):

You can use **react-native-animated-splash** package for splash animation.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install any   extra dependencies use this function method:

```
   const FunctionName = ({ navigation }) => {

   setTimeout(() => {

    navigation.replace('name') // there you have to give the name of page

  }, 1500) 

  return (
    //design the page
  )};
```

Now go to `App.js` page and

```
 <Stack.Screen 
        name="name" //name the page 
        component={Poems} // call function of the page where you want to navigate
        />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but how to achieve this animation https://www.kapwing.com/videos/64bd30a9edaa9f00d11a74c9    here is a video I want this animation.